# Best practice for jquery powered UI on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have about 40 lines of code that's currently wrapped in doc.ready in the head of my page. It's all UI related stuff that will be used on every page of the website. Stuff like: scroll back to top button, fixed header background goes darker once scroll past certain height, .load to load html into a div container, etc...

Since the js will be used on every page of the website, what's the best practice? Should I leave it as is and just move it to the footer of my page?

Or should I still create a default.js file that loads it in? Fairly new at this so any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the same script on multiple pages, then yes, it probably makes sense to put it in a separate `.js` file and reference it from each page (I do that anyway, even if only using the JavaScript on one page). And yes, if you control where the `<script>` tags are, there's rarely any reason to use `ready`, just put the `<script>` tags at the bottom, just before the closing `</body>` tag. References for that last:

- [Google on when DOM elements are available](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)
- [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize if I put the script tag at the bottom it would run the code when the page finished loading. Makes sense now that you point it out but I didn't clue in :)

Answer (score 3):

If it's used in every page I'd suggest moving it to its own js file. This will allow the browser to cache it and reduce your page size.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice should be to use an external js file included using script tag. This script tag should be ideally placed just before the closing body tag (`</body>`) but can be put in the head part with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to have separated the code for the javascript to an external file and call it from the header of the webpage. It is good to avoid mixing code :)

Comment: It is not best practice to have it in the header of the page. [Reference](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

Comment: It's not always best practice to separate into another file. Take for example a script with only a few lines. If you separate this into its own JS file the browser has to make a request to fetch it. This increases bandwidth to your server, decreases page load performance for new visitors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Never put JavaScript directly into your HTML. Technically, it *could* invalidate otherwise perfectly well-formed HTML. However, browsers nowadays are smart enough to get around that. But putting it in their own file(s), usually enables caching. What I typically do is put all my site-wide JavaScript stuff in one file and then, the page specific stuff in another.